Reversing XOR operation
Consider the XOR operation,
$$A = B \oplus C$$
I know $A$ but I don't know $B$ or $C$.
Question: Can I get $B$ or $C$ from $A$ ?

6 ⊕ 11 = 15, 5 ⊕ 14 = 15, 7 ⊕ 11 = 15. So how will you know which one is it? So many more answers like this

Agree. This question relates to my earlier one:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/106932/xor-for-more-trng-data

No you can't reverse XOR with only the knowledge of the result.
Knowing the value of $A$ tells us only which bits are the same or different between $B$ and $C$, and if at least one of them is indistinguishable from random noise then this information will be useless as $A$ will also be indistinguishable from random noise. Take for example the simple case of $B=0$, $C=1$, XOR them together and you get $A=1$. Someone knowing the value of $A$ can say that the first (and in this case only) bit of $B$ and $C$ is different, but doesn't know which one has what value. And if each bit of $B$ has a 50/50 probability of being either one or zero then each bit of $A$ also has a 50/50 probability of being either one or zero, regardless of the value of $C$. This is assuming that the values of $B$ and $C$ are unrelated, such as the case where one is an encryption key and the other is the plaintext for example, or the case where they are two streams of sampled entropy from different sources.
That property is the basis for many different cryptography algorithms and protocols. For example the CTR encryption mode that most internet security relies on. A key stream ($B$ in your example) is generated and XORed with the plaintext ($C$) to get a ciphertext ($A$). If it was possible to calculate the plaintext from the ciphertext alone, without knowing the key, then this type of encryption would be completely broken.
